# Amplify server error "Cannot read property 'Minus' of undefined"

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-cli

Драствуйте, делал все по [*инструкции*](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-appsync-chat-starter-angular/tree/626e40df392c88b8d43d843d31bec0118a262acf) амазона точь-в-точь, но все равно ничего не работает. Пару ошибок удалось пофиксить, но на этой встрял:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'Minus' of undefined
See "/tmp/ng-wdv6Ud/angular-errors.log" for further details.
frontend start command exited with code 127
```

[image: ошибка]

Данные из этого файла:

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'Minus' of undefined
    at /opt/*****/aws-mobile-appsync-chat-starter-angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/translator/src/translator.js:23:26
    at /opt/*****/aws-mobile-appsync-chat-starter-angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/translator/src/translator.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/*****/aws-mobile-appsync-chat-starter-angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/translator/src/translator.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at /opt/*****/aws-mobile-appsync-chat-starter-angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/translator/index.js:24:24
    at /opt/*****/aws-mobile-appsync-chat-starter-angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/translator/index.js:10:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/*****/aws-mobile-appsync-chat-starter-angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/translator/index.js:16:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
```

Я в этом вообще не разбираюсь, поэтому если вы знаете решение, пишите с командами пожалуйста